# Asp.NET Ajax Application (.NET framework 4.0) upgrade option

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-ajax, .net-framework-version

I have an ASP.net Ajax application that was written years ago. It is in .NET version 4.0 in VS 2010. I would like to upgrade it to .NET version 4.6 using VS 2017. Would you know if this would cause problem in .NET version 4.6 or VS 2017 ?  Is there a new version of AjaxControlToolKit for .NET version 4.6 ?

Obviously I am doing this in a safer approach, since this application impacts quite big.

Highly appreciated your response!

Have a great day!

Comment: is any update? Please check if my answer works for you.

Comment: Thanks for your follow up. I will use your instructions to try. There is an update on AjaxControlToolKit for VS2017. I think I will be able to manage the change.

Answer (score 0):

As usual, it is normal for you to get the problem when you migrate from lower version to higher version.

You can get some advice from the similar link:

[How do I update a 2008 project to work with Visual Studio 2017?](https://forums.asp.net/t/2141499.aspx?How%20do%20I%20update%20a%202008%20project%20to%20work%20with%20Visual%20Studio%202017%20)

If you want to update AjaxControlToolKit in the new version of visual studio, you can refer to the Microsoft doc.

[Updating the ASP.NET AJAX Control Toolkit Assembly](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb907623(v=vs.100)#updating-the-aspnet-ajax-control-toolkit-assembly)

Hope the above link can help you.